# How to select and check changes of DropDownList in GridView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a ASP.NET GridView control and DropDownList control inside the GridiView as below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I wanted to use jQuery/ JavaScript to get DropDownList element and detect the item change as below:

```
$(function() {
    $("#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>").change(function() {
        if ($("#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>").find('option:selected').text() == "1") {
            alert('1');
        } else {
            alert('2');
        }
    });
});
```

My question is, how can I select the DropDownList inside GridView, and then check for the changes?

Please advise.
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign a css `class` to dropdownlist and `bind` event with class, using [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

*Html*

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="ddlclass">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

*Javascript*

```
$(function() {
    $(".ddlclass").change(function() {
        if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == "1") {
            alert('1');
        } else {
            alert('2');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In your html, class attribute should be in asp:DropDownList element. And I think it's better the CssClass server side attribute.

Comment: Ah, very good, but the class needs to be assigned to the drop down list and not to the gridview as you are showing. Correct it and you have my vote. :)

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying is bit difficult use like this

```
 $("input[id*=DropDownList1]")

$(function() {
     $("input[id*=DropDownList1]").change(function() {
        if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == "1") {
            alert('1');
        } else {
            alert('2');
        }
    });
});
```

**But make sure you don't have any control id like `DropDownList1`**

Comment: +1 this will also work although I have the feeling that the class selector may be faster...

Answer (score 0):

Try using with `.find()`:

```
$(function() {
   $("#GridView1").find("[id^='DropDownList']").change(function() {
      if ($('option:selected',this).text() == "1") {
          alert('1');
      } else {
          alert('2');
      }
   });
});
```

I don't work in `.net` environment so its a total guess, might be useful.

Note: *`The above line only work if your ids are starting with DropDownList`.*

Comment: as there will be many dropdown list so I don't think this is going to work.